# changing controlled component state in semanticUI

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I do not understand how semanticUI grabs the value from its components.

In the following example how does the handlechange function communicate with the dropdown. From my understanding when an option from the dropdown is clicked it sets the state locally to the value of that option. But how does the `handleChange` method do that?

```
handleChange = (e , { value }) => this.setState({ course:value})
```

I do not understand where { value } is coming from. When I do `console.log(e.currentTarget)` I get the html element and can see what value it holds by expanding it so why can I not do `handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ course:e.currentTarget.value })`

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lobc7f)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Grid, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
export default class CourseDropDown extends Component {
  state = {}

  handleChange = (e , { value }) => this.setState({ course:value})


  render() {
    const options = [
        { key: 1, text: 'Calculus I', value: 'Calculus I' },
        { key: 2, text: 'Calculus II', value: 'Calculus II' },
        { key: 3, text: 'Calculus III', value: 'Calculus III' }
      ]
    const { course } = this.state
    return (
      <Grid columns={2}>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Dropdown
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
            placeholder='Choose a course'
            selection
            value={course}
          />
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Segment secondary>
            <pre>Current course: {course}</pre>
          </Segment>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a known limitation. The event.target is a browser event property. However, many Semantic UI components, such as a Dropdown, Checkbox, and Radio do not work directly with native browser form controls such as input and select. They are built using stylized markup and custom internal state.
>
> Because of this, there are no native browser events available for certain callbacks. This is why all change events in Semantic-UI-React provide the event first (when available) but also a second argument which contains the data you need. You should never have to access the native browser event for most tasks.
>
> You can see examples of how to retrieve values from the second argument in the docs. Such as the Radio Group example.
>
> Going to close this issue as this is not a bug. Feel free to open another issue if you feel any components are missing helpful data in the second argument and we can add more callback data.

Taken from https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/638

I have also refactored your code to help you understand it a bit better.

```javascript
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Grid, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class CourseDropDown extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      course: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange(e, data) {
    this.setState({ course: data.value })
  }

  render() {
    const options = [
        { key: 1, text: 'Calculus I', value: 'Calculus I' },
        { key: 2, text: 'Calculus II', value: 'Calculus II' },
        { key: 3, text: 'Calculus III', value: 'Calculus III' }
      ]
    const { course } = this.state
    return (
      <Grid columns={2}>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Dropdown
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
            placeholder="Choose a course"
            selection
            value={course}
          />
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Segment secondary>
            <pre>Current course: {course}</pre>
          </Segment>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}

export default CourseDropDown;
```

Good luck!